# JSON Exception: java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm having a JSON Exception being thrown and I don't know why it is being thrown. I've taken a look at almost all of the other questions that are just like mine, but I think mine is different. So I am getting a JSONArray from a webpage, and the JSON it sends is valid (I checked it with a validator). The exception is being thrown when I perform getJSONObject on the JSONArray.

Here's exactly what it says (personal information is starred out):

```
org.json.JSONException: Value  [{"name":"*****","profilePicture":"*****"}] at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

And here's my Java code:

```
 protected Void doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = params[0];
        ClientServerInterface clientServerInterface = new ClientServerInterface();
        JSONArray attendanceDetails = clientServerInterface.postData("http://54.164.136.46/get_attendance.php", jsonObject);
        Log.e("Attendance Details: ", attendanceDetails.toString());

        nameAttendees = new String[attendanceDetails.length()];
        pictureAttendees = new String[attendanceDetails.length()];

        JSONObject jobj = null;
 for(int i = 0; i < attendanceDetails.length(); i++)
        {
            try {
                jobj = attendanceDetails.getJSONObject(i);
                nameAttendees[i] = jobj.getString("name");
                pictureAttendees[i] = jobj.getString("profilePicture");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The error is happening at the line where I go:

```
jobj = attendanceDetails.getJSONObject(i);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code seem correct. Can you post few more line above the for loop?

Comment: Can you post the JSON you are trying to parse? It looks like the element you try to parse is a string `["name"]` while you are expecting an object `[{"name": "name"}]`

Comment: The JSON is in the OP in the exception

Comment: Added code above loop

Comment: Oh I see something strange. I printed out the JSONArray and here is what it is: `[" [{\"name\":\"*****\",\"profilePicture\":\"*****\"}]\n"]`

Comment: But JSONLint tells me it is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < attendanceDetails.length(); i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONArray hello = new JSONArray(attendanceDetails.getJSONArray(i));
            JSONObject jObject = new  JSONObject(hello.get(i).toString());
            nameAttendees[i] = jObject.getString("name");
            pictureAttendees[i] = jObject.getString("profilePicture");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The variable jobj is of type JSONObject. So should I cast it to JSONObject, since .get returns type Object?

Comment: Now I'm getting this exception:
`java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject`

Comment: You can't.when you use get function.You can get a String in your example .though the String is a object.It can's convert to JSONObject,unless it is a real object instead of subclass of object.

Comment: Here's what I did:
`JSONObject jObject =  new JSONObject(attendanceDetails.get(i).toString());
                    nameAttendees[i] = jObject.getString("name");
                    pictureAttendees[i] = jObject.getString("profilePicture");`

And error is JSONArray cannot be converted into JSONObject

Comment: Can you print the jobj when you use attendanceDeails.get(i).

Comment: `[" [{\"name\":\"*****\",\"profilePicture\":\"*****\"}]\n"]`

Comment: I see.The correct format is  "{\"name\":\"*****\",\"profilePicture\":\"*****\"}" instead of " [{\"name\":\"*****\",\"profilePicture\":\"*****\"}]\n".It will be recognized an array when you use "[" .So you should print the attendanceDetails.I think it is not the format you hope

Comment: So how should I fix this?

Comment: JSONArray hello =  new JSONArray(attendanceDetails.getJSONArray(i));JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(hello.get(i).toString());

Comment: WOW BUDDY THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKS. Also edit your top answer to this. So why was this happening?

Comment: I think the correct format is [{},{},{}].However your format is [[{}],[{}],[{}]].So it's weird